# Magento 1.7.0.2 Catalog prices reindex issue after edit product in admin

Tags: magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7.0.2. When I add product in admin everything is working fine but, when I edit and save this product in prices category page is not updated and product page shows updated price. Also price reindex is not working after editing product. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Is ur compilation is disabled or enabled?? if enable, make it disable by going through system/tools/compilation.. Then re-index the data by system/Index Management.. Here select all the make reindex of them . Now final clear your cache by cache management..

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for response. compilation is disabled but, issue occures when I edit product. when I delete that product which is edited then reindexing works but after edit product occures the same error again

Comment: Then ur problem is with index management.. It is not working as expected. Try on resolving the index management issue

Comment: Did u installed any new extension related to the configurable products or any other?? If yes, try on disabling the extension and update the price and check it. I think it is getting conflict with the new extension.

Comment: No new extensions are installed.  It was working few days ago

Comment: Can someone expalin it that why there is no issue (with price indexing ) during product adding. issue occurs only when I update product?